# Use mockito to mock final classes and common interfaces

Tags: spring-boot, maven, unit-testing, mockito, junit4

I'm using Mockito (3.6.x) for my unit tests in Spring Boot (2.4.x) with JUnit 4. There are unit tests where I need to mock final classes (e.g. `java.lang.reflect.Method`), and there are other unit tests where I need to mock common interfaces (e.g. `org.springframework.core.env.Environment`).

I have tried many solutions but none have worked for me. I found this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-final) where I can mock final classes, but when I add the `mock-inline-maker` plugin, only unit tests that mock final classes work (classes in which I mock `java.lang.reflect.Method`) and the others crash (classes in which I mock `org.springframework.core.env.Environment`), and vice versa when I remove the `mock-inline-maker`.

Is there a way to configure the mock-inline-maker for some classes in the test and not for others?

P.S. The only reason to mock final classes is to achieve this code block in my unit tests:

```
MethodSignature methodSignature = (MethodSignature) proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature();
Method method = signature.getMethod();
CustomAnnotation customAnnotation = method.getAnnotation(CustomAnnotation.class);
```

I thank you all very much.

Comment: Why do you want to mock `Method` and `Environment`? They arent `static final` objects... just create new instances for your test cases, assuming the actual code uses them.

Comment: Actually yes, ```Method``` is a final class according to [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html), and Mockito throws an error when I try to mock/stub final classes.

Comment: I mean that you can create an instance of `Method`/`Environment` set up in a way to test your code, not that you can necessarily extend them.

Comment: @j1mbl3s How can I do that? I tried to create an instance of ```Method``` but I could not, Java did not let me since ```Method``` is a final class.

Comment: [`Class.getMethods()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethods()) returns a `Method[]` array. Create a class with some methods that you want to test your functionality with.

Comment: OK, I have already done this, but my code now throws a vulnerability of kind Broken Access Control in my quality scans. I read about this on [Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/seccodeguide.html#9). I can not let my code with this issue. Please, do you have another idea?

Comment: A BAC sounds like another issue entirely...

Comment: Ok @j1mbl3s, thanks for your help!, I will make another question, using PowerMockito this time.